# Putting mutliple fields into a Field Name with SQL for XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Issue: I want to put the more data that is true from the 'group' inside the parent XML field that encompasses the other, child fields.

Query: Can I bundle up details that are the same into one Field to save file size and import time.

```
<ParentField Field1="1" Field2="X" Field3="SomeText">
```

Additionally is what I am trying to do good practice or should I keep what I have

Some fields, on top of the UPRN, such as data, as also able to go into a parent value. I have seen code like this:

Using the SQL code I have, how might I modify to it that? (Snippet below)

```
USE DATABASE

SELECT      
      e.GroupFieldName,

      (SELECT 
      c.ShouldBeParent AS ShouldBeParent
      ,c.ChildIsOkayHere AS ChildIsOkayHere

      FROM TblTableC c
      WHERE c.GroupFieldName = e.GroupFieldName 
      FOR XML PATH('LineItem'), type
      )

  FROM TblTableE e
  JOIN
  TblTableC c 
  ON e.GroupFieldName = c.UPRN  

  GROUP BY e.UPRN

FOR XML PATH('GroupFieldName') , ROOT ('SURVEYDATA')
```

Example (of what I have):

```
<SURVEYDATA>
  <UPRN_GROUP>
    <UPRN>SH1001</UPRN>
 <CHILD>
      <Field1>Some Text </Field1>
</CHILD> 
<CHILD>
      <Field1>Some Other Text </Field1>
</CHILD> 
  </UPRN_GROUP>
  <UPRN_GROUP>
    <UPRN>SH1001</UPRN>
 <CHILD>
      <Field1>Some Text </Field1>
</CHILD> 
<CHILD>
      <Field1>Some Other Text </Field1>
</CHILD> 
  </UPRN_GROUP>
</SURVEYDATA>
```

Comment: Could you please give an example what output should be? Please use your "Example (of what I have), copy this, and modify it the way you want. And please give the structure of your data source with some sample data. Best create a Fiddle

Comment: Added line of code, I must of forgotten/missed it out. I had it in my notepad doddles! It would go where <UPRN> is now

Comment: Hi, if my answer could help you to solve your problem, it would be very kind to vote it up and - if it helped you to solve this - mark it as accepted. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must find your solution yourself, as you provide not enough information. Read about FOR XML PATH.

Following you will find a bunch of statements to play around. Copy them into an empty query window and execute. Look especially on the way I named the columns. Names with "@" will be attributes, "pure" names will be elements.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT, Caption VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'Caption 1'),(2,'Caption 2'),(3,'Caption 3');

DECLARE @tblChildren TABLE(id INT,ParentId INT,Caption VARCHAR(100));
INSERt INTO @tblChildren VALUES(1,1,'Caption 1.1'),(2,1,'Caption 1.2'),(3,1,'Caption 1.3')
                              ,(4,2,'Caption 2.1'),(5,2,'Caption 2.2')
                              ,(6,3,'Caption 3.1');

--Simple SELECT
SELECT tbl.id AS ParentId
      ,tbl.Caption AS ParentCaption
      ,ch.id AS ChildId 
      ,ch.Caption AS ChildCaption
FROM @tbl AS tbl
INNER JOIN @tblChildren AS ch ON tbl.id=ch.ParentId;

--XML with elements and attributes (play around with this...)
--Children are not nested...
SELECT tbl.Caption AS [Parent/@Caption]
      ,tbl.id AS [Parent/@Id]
      ,ch.Caption AS [Child/@Caption]
      ,ch.id AS [Child/@Id] 
FROM @tbl AS tbl
INNER JOIN @tblChildren AS ch ON tbl.id=ch.ParentId
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root');

--XML with elements and attributes (play around with this...)
--Children are blocked...
SELECT tbl.Caption AS [Parent/@ParentCaption]
      ,tbl.id AS [Parent/@Id]
      ,(SELECT id AS [@id]
              ,Caption AS [@Caption]
        FROM @tblChildren 
        WHERE ParentId=tbl.id
        FOR XML PATH('Child'),ROOT('Children'),TYPE
        )
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root');

--XML with elements and attributes (play around with this...)
--Children are nested...
--No row-tag needed, as everything is nested
SELECT tbl.Caption AS [Parent/@ParentCaption]
      ,tbl.id AS [Parent/@Id]
      ,(SELECT id AS [@id]
              ,Caption AS [@Caption]
        FROM @tblChildren 
        WHERE ParentId=tbl.id
        FOR XML PATH('Child'),TYPE
        ) AS [Parent/Children]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root');
```